# How to make the map fit inside div boxes in display table

Tags: html, css, openlayers

I want to render maps like this way by using `display:table`.
[image: display:table]

But it seems that it doesn't follow fixed height, making div bigger when I clicked a button
for showing 4 maps.
I set 50% height for `map13` when clicked `button #four`.
[image]
Is there a way to make the map fit inside div boxes? or should I not use display:table?

```js
function divideMap(divisionType) {
  $('#map24').css('display', 'none');
  $('#map3').css('display', 'none');

  if (divisionType === 'four') {
    $('#map13').css('height', '50%');
    $('#map13').css('width', 'auto');

    $('#map24').css('display', 'table-row');
    $('#map3,#map4').css('display', 'table-cell');
  } else if (divisionType === 'two vertical') {
    $('#map3').css('display', 'table-cell');
  } else if (divisionType === 'two horizontal') {
    $('#map24').css('display', 'table-row');
    $('#map4').css('display', 'none');
  } else {

  }
  mainMap.updateSize();
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#header {
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: silver;
  float: left;
}

#main {
  height: 90%;
  width: 100%;
}

#contents {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#fullscreen {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

#map13 {
  display: table-row;
}

#map1 {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#map3 {
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#map24 {
  display: none;
}

#map2 {
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: darkslategray;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#map4 {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">
  <button onclick="divideMap('original')">reset</button>
  <button onclick="divideMap('two vertical')">two vertical</button>
  <button onclick="divideMap('two horizontal')">two horizontal</button>
  <button onclick="divideMap('four')">four</button>
</div>
<div id="main">
  <div id="contents">
    <div id="fullscreen">
      <div id="map13">
        <div id="map1">
        </div>
        <div id="map3">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="map24">
        <div id="map2">
        </div>
        <div id="map4">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you want to use `div` with `display: table`? Instead why couldn't you use `table` itself ?

Comment: IMHO You probably will have better luck using a grid-layout . the table-layout expands to fit the contents it holds also colspan and rowspan behavior cannot be replicated via CSS, but grid has placement options.